# images fetched via JSON takes time to load in android

Tags: android, json

i am fetching text and images via JSON, text loads quickly but images are taking some time to load. How to make it fast?? Here is my code for fetching image from JSON and loading

public class FetchHyperVChannelInfo extends AsyncTask> {

```
final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
final String KEY_THUMB = "url";
HyperV hyperV;

final String KEY_VIDEO_ID = "videoId";
final String KEY_DESCRIPTION = "description";
final String KEY_POSITION = "position";

public FetchHyperVChannelInfo(HyperV context)
{
    hyperV = context;
}

@Override
protected List<HyperVBean> doInBackground(Void... params) {
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    String channeljsonString;
    List<HyperVBean> hyperBeanList = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        String base_uri = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?";
        Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(base_uri).buildUpon()
                .appendQueryParameter("part", "snippet")
                .appendQueryParameter("maxResults", "50")
                .appendQueryParameter("playlistId", "PLjnOm_giI__5EiPY3GS7tr59pdAlvxd46")
                .appendQueryParameter("key", "AIzaSyBRdEqF_FW-LF1ru4ejnZYxt_nYwSehl3w").build();

        URL url = new URL(builtUri.toString());
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.connect();

        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
        if (inputStream == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            buffer.append(line).append("\n");
        }
        if (buffer.length() == 0)
        {
            return null;
        }
        channeljsonString = buffer.toString();
        getDataFromJson(channeljsonString, hyperBeanList);

    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        if (urlConnection != null)
        {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        if (reader != null)
        {
            try
            {
                reader.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    }
    return hyperBeanList;
}

public void getDataFromJson(String StringChannelJson, List<HyperVBean> channelList) throws JSONException
{
    JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject(StringChannelJson);
    JSONArray jsonArray = mainObject.getJSONArray("items");
    HyperVBean bean1 = new HyperVBean();

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
    {
        JSONObject channelObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

        HyperVBean bean = new HyperVBean();

        JSONObject temp = channelObject.getJSONObject("snippet");

        bean.setHyperBeanName(temp.getString(KEY_TITLE));

        JSONObject thumburl = channelObject.getJSONObject("snippet").getJSONObject("thumbnails").getJSONObject("maxres");

        String s = thumburl.getString(KEY_THUMB);

        bean.setHyperBeanImages(thumburl.getString(KEY_THUMB));

        JSONObject tempDesc = channelObject.getJSONObject("snippet");

        JSONObject tempPosition = channelObject.getJSONObject("snippet");

        JSONObject videoId = channelObject.getJSONObject("snippet").getJSONObject("resourceId");

        bean.setHypervVideoDescArray(tempDesc.getString(KEY_DESCRIPTION));
        bean.setHypervPositionArray(tempPosition.getString(KEY_POSITION));
        bean.setHypervVideosArray(videoId.getString(KEY_VIDEO_ID));
        channelList.add(bean);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<HyperVBean> channelList) {
    hyperV.onPostExecute(channelList);
}
```

}

Here is my code for adapter class.

public class HyperVAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

```
private LayoutInflater inflater;
List<String> videoIdArray = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> videoDescArray = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> videoPositionArray = new ArrayList<String>();

public static class ViewHolder
{
    public final TextView hyperVName;
    public final ImageView hyperVImages;

    public ViewHolder(View view)
    {
        hyperVName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nameHyperVRowLayout);
        hyperVImages = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageHyperVRowLayout);
    }
}

public HyperVAdapter(Context context, int resources,  List<HyperVBean> objects)
{
    super(context, R.layout.row_layout_hyper, objects);
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        view = vi.inflate(R.layout.row_layout_hyper, null);
    }
    final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
    HyperVBean hyperVBean = getItem(position);
    viewHolder.hyperVName.setText(hyperVBean.getHyperBeanName());
    Picasso.with(getContext()).load(hyperVBean.getHyperBeanImages()).into(viewHolder.hyperVImages);

    viewHolder.hyperVImages.setTag(position);
    viewHolder.hyperVImages.setClickable(true);

    videoIdArray.add(hyperVBean.getHypervVideosArray());
    videoDescArray.add(hyperVBean.getHypervVideoDescArray());
    videoPositionArray.add(hyperVBean.getHypervPositionArray());

    final String[] myVideoIdArray = new String[videoIdArray.size()];
    videoIdArray.toArray(myVideoIdArray);

    final String[] myVideoPosition = new String[videoPositionArray.size()];
    videoPositionArray.toArray(myVideoPosition);

    final String[] myVideoDesc = new String[videoDescArray.size()];
    videoDescArray.toArray(myVideoDesc);

    viewHolder.hyperVImages.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            int position = (Integer) v.getTag();
            for (int i = 0; i<myVideoPosition.length; i++)
            {
                if (position == Integer.parseInt(myVideoPosition[i]))
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), VideoScreen.class);
                    intent.putExtra("description", myVideoDesc[i]);
                    intent.putExtra("videoId", myVideoIdArray[i]);
                    intent.putExtra("position", myVideoPosition[i]);
                    getContext().startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

}

Comment: you must use picasso library http://square.github.io/picasso/ to load the images asyn

Comment: @QadirHussain yeah I am already using Picasso library, still its loading slowly

Comment: can you send me sample image url. I want to see the image size

Comment: @QadirHussain here is image url  "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/BqNqOrWkhOM/maxresdefault.jpg"

Comment: OK image is tiny. should not take too time to load. what do you mean by loading slowly.?

Comment: @QadirHussain means it takes 2 to 3 seconds and then the image appears on ImageView. I want that it should appear instantly.

Comment: picasso cache the images with url as ID I think. Images cached by picasso should load instantly.